# Current Window should seen on the top

Tags: web-applications

I am making an web based appliaction in java (using jsp). When the appliaction is invoked login page will come, when the user enter the valid credientials, he will be taken to the index page. But the problem is, when the login is success, the index page is coming but it is opening behind the login page. (means login page appears on the top of the monitor, I want index page should appear on the top of the window.) Can anyone help me out in this...Please

Answer (score 2):

Programming in a browser doesn't support modal windows in the way you mean - to do this you really need to be writing a 'desktop' application.

The simplest solution is to redirect the browser to the login page (remembering the page the user requested), handle the login and then redirect back to the requested page.

Answer (score 2):

You should reconsider your design.

Having a webapp with an extra login page that comes up and a functionality that requires ordering windows is not going to work in a consequent manner on different browser and not even in the same browser.

modern webbrowser more and more use tabs for opening new windows and more and more people are getting used to it.
Even before tabbed browsing it was not easily done.

Work with 1 single window and just navigate in the same window.